# How to clear all loaded values in material autocomplete angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, form-control

I am trying to clear all the loaded values in a material input field on selectionchange of another mat-select field. I am able to clear only the selected value and not able to clear all the loaded values in the input field `property`. Here is the code.

**HTML**:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select formControlName="searchType" (selectionChange)="searchTypeChange()" placeholder="Search By">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let st of searchTypes" [value]="st.value">
            {{st.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field *ngIf="searchForm.get('searchType').value==6" class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="PropertyID" [formControl] ="property"    [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" autoActiveFirstOption>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of propertyfilteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
            {{option}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Typescript**:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchForm=this.fb.group({
       prop:this.property,
    });
}
searchTypeChange(){
    this.searchForm.get('prop').setValue('');
    this.property.reset(); //this is not working
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to reset FormControl. It doesn't provide data to MatSelect. It gets data from subscription -`propertyfilteredOptions | async`. You need to pass new values to `propertyfilteredOptions` Observable.

You can also f.ex. just change it to a new Observable:

```
this.propertyfilteredOptions = new Observable([]);
```